# ; expected { expected in visual studio 2015 in a .cs file program. It's a math formula

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to develop games and for the basics I need to learn to code c# in Visual Studio 2015. It's a c# file and the code is as follows-

It is basically a code based on finding the distance between 2 points.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program_yash
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my program! Here, we're going to find the distance between 2 points in a cartesian coordinate system and the angle between them");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the x value of the 1st coordinate.");
            float pointX1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the y value of the 1st coordinate.");
            float pointY1 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the x value of the 2nd coordinate.");
            float pointX2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the y value of the 2nd coordinate.");
            float pointY2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double distance = Math.Sqrt( (((double)pointX2 - (double)pointX1)) - ((double)pointY2 - (double)pointY1)) * (((double)pointX2 - (double)pointX1))-((double)pointY2 - (double)pointY1)) );
            Console.WriteLine("The distance between the points is :" + distance);
        }
    }
}
```

The error shown is as below -

```
line 22    ; expected
line 22    { expected
```

Supression state is active. I don't know where I'm going wrong. I used to do c# on Turbo C and it way easier than this.

Comment: Why are you parsing the input to `float` if you're just going to cast to `double`?  Why not just parse to `double` right away?

Comment: @Kyle I need to do further coding where I need to use only float. So, this is just a part of the program. I've just snipped this part of the code and pasted it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses on the line with `Math.Sqrt()` are not balanced. Go through them carefully. You may find this easier if you break up that complicated expression into multiple statements.

```
double XDiff = (double)pointX2 - (double)pointX1;
double YDiff = (double)pointY2 - (double)pointY1;
double squared = (XDiff - YDiff) * (XDiff - YDiff); //weirdest distance formula I've ever seen ;)
double distance = Math.Sqrt(squared);
distance = Math.Sqrt( (XDiff * XDiff) + (YDiff * YDiff) ); //now that looks better
```

Another trick is to treat the parentheses like braces, and put things on multiple lines in a simple text editor while building the expression. Here is an example using the exact parentheses posted in the question:

```
( /* open method */
    (
        (
            (double)pointX2 - (double)pointX1
        )
    ) - 
    (
        (double)pointY2 - (double)pointY1
    )

) /* end method */   * 

(
    (
        (double)pointX2 - (double)pointX1
    )
)-
(
    (double)pointY2 - (double)pointY1
)

/***** Uh oh. These are extra and don't have matching open parens *****/
) 
)
```

See how that makes it clear where we have extra closing parens. Once you're sure things are balanced and correct, you can collapse it back down to a single line for pasting back into the code.

Since it seems like you could use some practice, I'll leave building the actual corrected expression up to you.

Comment: That was it. And when I reviewed the formula it was mathematically incorrect. It's supposed to be sqrt[(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2]

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line into this. As the way you are arranging is misleading for compiler.

```
  double distance = Math.Sqrt(( (((double)pointX2 - (double)pointX1)) - ((double)pointY2 - (double)pointY1)) * ((((double)pointX2 - (double)pointX1))-((double)pointY2 - (double)pointY1 )));
```